# How can I guess that a combination of Atbasch and Caesar / Vigenère has been used?

Tags: cryptanalysis

If I'm given a ciphertext, what kind of patterns, index of coincidence, frequency analysis would lead me to guess that it had been encrypted by a combination of Atbasch plus Caesar / Vigenère?

Comment: Have you tried writing down a probabilistic model for the result?  See, _e.g._, Alan Turing's [Applications of Probability Theory to Cryptanalysis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04714).